# Typescript type flow analysis

Tags: typescript, types

I found a case where typescripts type guards and flow analysis are behaving unexpectedly.  I hesitate to call it a bug, I don't really know how it's *supposed* to work.  In my experience, usually it just magically does what I want.

```
class Parent { }
class Child extends Parent { 
    other: Child;
}

let x: Parent = null;
if (x instanceof Child) {
    x = x.other;
    x = x.other;  // this line gives a compilation error
}
```

You can try this out on the [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).  The reported compilation error doesn't make sense to me.

> Property 'other' does not exist on type 'Parent'.

I would assume that inside the `if` block, that `x` is typed as `Child`.  Why is this happening?  Is there a decent workaround?

Answer (score 1):

In your first `x = x.other;` that right side `x` considered as `Child`. And it's right, since it stays within `if (x instanceof Child){...}`.
The left side `x` considered as `Parent`, we can say that it's also right, since you declared `let x: Parent`.

This contradiction may be a little buggy, but on other hand you can blame yourself, because you try to confuse the compiler in any way by conflicting declarations... :)

So on your second `x = x.other;` the right side `x` is considered as `Parent` (as a left side `x` on previous line), so you get `Property 'other' does not exist on type 'Parent'.`

Comment: You say "The right side `x` considered as `Parent`".  If that were true, the first assignment would be the compilation error, not the second.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo.. I mean the left side